# How to design a pivot table from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, pivot, pivot-table

I have tried alot to accomplish this to no success, so im here for help. I will try to give full details so i can help myself get the best needed solution.

from my MySQL Database

```
Table (students)
--------------------------------
studentID | class_id | and other info


Table (class)
-------------------------------
classID | name | other info


Table (subjects)
--------------------------------
subjectID | name | class_id (references Class.classID)


Table (exam_type)
--------------------------------
exam_typeID | name | desc | start_date


Table (result)
---------------------------------------------
student_id | exam_type_id | subject_id | mark
```

In my query i have this:

```
SELECT subjects.name, exam_type.name, result.mark FROM subjects 
LEFT JOIN result ON result.subject_id=subjects.subjectID 
JOIN exam_type ON exam_type.exam_typeID=result.exam_type_id 
WHERE result.student_id=$x 
ORDER BY 
subjects.name, exam_type.name
```

In the query $x is the id of the student to show his/her result

the query returns this

[image: results shown, from dummy data in my database]

Pretty much to this level i am okay now my headache is i want to displace the result in such a way...see my design already.

[image: front end]

its going to be really helpful if somebody point me to the right direction to diplace the info in the first picture as such.

```
----------------------------------------------
                            CA Tests  | Exams
-----------------------------------------------
subjects             |  1  |  2  |  3 | score
-----------------------------------------------
Agricultural science | 10  | 9   | 8  | 56
-----------------------------------------------
English language     | 12  | 13  | 12 | 43
-----------------------------------------------
French Language      | 11  |     |    |
```

**SOLVED:** by JIML's solution 
[image: solved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change SQL so you don't get two columns with the same name

```
SELECT subjects.name, exam_type.name, result.mark FROM subjects 
-->
SELECT subjects.name, exam_type.name as test, result.mark FROM subjects
```

Then you can do something like this (I've simulated the result from the db)

```
$result = array(
  0 => array(
    'name' => 'Agricultural Science',
    'test' => 'CA 1',
    'mark' => 10
  ),
  1 => array(
    'name' => 'Agricultural Science',
    'test' => 'CA 2',
    'mark' => 9
  ),
  2 => array(
    'name' => 'Agricultural Science',
    'test' => 'CA 3',
    'mark' => 8
  ),
  3 => array(
    'name' => 'Agricultural Science',
    'test' => 'Exam',
    'mark' => 56
  ),
  4 => array(
    'name' => 'English Language',
    'test' => 'CA 1',
    'mark' => 12
  ),
  5 => array(
    'name' => 'English Language',
    'test' => 'CA 2',
    'mark' => 13
  ),
  6 => array(
    'name' => 'English Language',
    'test' => 'CA 3',
    'mark' => 12
  ),
  7 => array(
    'name' => 'English Language',
    'test' => 'Exam',
    'mark' => 43
  )
);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[$row['name']]['marks'][$row['test']] = $row['mark'];
}

?>
CA test | Exams<br />
<?php
foreach ($data as $name => $row) {
  echo $name . ' | ' . $row['marks']['CA 1'] . ' | ' . $row['marks']['CA 2'] . ' | ' . $row['marks']['CA 3'] . ' | ' . $row['marks']['Exam'] . '<br />';
}
```

Output

```
CA test | Exams
Agricultural Science | 10 | 9 | 8 | 56
English Language | 12 | 13 | 12 | 43
```

Then just add it to however you generate tables.